# Do Lists have something similar to an Enumerators MoveNext method?

Tags: c#, list

I am building a program where I read from a file and put each line of the file into a list of objects.

```
   List<DataRecord> vListOfRecords = new List<DataRecord>();
```

Earlier I did the same [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725392/trying-to-come-up-with-control-break-logic-for-a-sum-program) but I was instructed to read the data into an object and put those objects into a List<>, don't ask why please.  So that I could sort the items.

Anyways I am doing my best to mimic my loop from the link I provided but I can't find a way to set a boolean to List.MoveNext() method.  So is there a method with Lists that can do this?

Or is there a way to break from this while loop that I am not seeing?

```
    //Sort list by control vaiable.
        if (control == "1")
        {
            SortByAccount sortByAccount = new SortByAccount();
            vListOfRecords.Sort(sortByAccount);

            //set up control for account to switch
            var vAccount = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataRecord d in vListOfRecords)
            {


                do
                {
                    var vParseSettleMM = d.settleMM;
                    var vParseOpen = d.open;
                    var vParseBuy = d.buy;
                    var vParseSell = d.sell;

                    //adding temp variabels to sum
                    vSettleMMSum += vParseSettleMM;
                    vOpenSum += vParseOpen;
                    vBuySum += vParseBuy;
                    vSellSum += vParseSell;

                }
                //sets up when to loop
                while (vAccount == d.account);

                //After each Break need to print out Account name and sums from above.
                // Do printing here as part of the loop, at the very end of the loop code block.
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");

                Console.WriteLine(vAccount + "  " + vSettleMMSum + "  " + vOpenSum + "   " + vBuySum + " " +
                    vSellSum);

                vWriteFile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", vAccount, vOpenSum, vBuySum, vSellSum, vSettleMMSum);

                //reset sums for next loop
                vSettleMMSum = 0;
                vOpenSum = 0;
                vBuySum = 0;
                vSellSum = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is vague, move when? What I got was: You could use continue inside the loop to do the logic and move to the next record.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use a LINQ where to only get the items you want instead of loop/break? vListOfRecords.Where(x=>x.account==vAccount ) or similar...something about that print? You can group with linq, if you post some sample data we can probably show you how

Comment: Every `IEnumerable` has a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an `IEnumerator`. `GetNext` is defined on `IEnumerator`. This is exactly what the `foreach` syntax sugar is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Lists have an underlying Enumerator you can use to get at the MoveNext method:

```
List<Something> somelist = new List<Something>();

List<Something>.Enumerator enumerator = somelist.GetEnumerator();

enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the desired result the way you are asking (using MoveNext inside a foreach loop)

You have two simple options:

- Process the list in a for loop and access items by index (instead of foreach) so you can nest two for loops and break whenever you want (your "MoveNext" would be index++)
- Use linq to group your list and process it grouped

Sample code of linq GroupBy :

```
var grouped = vListOfRecords.GroupBy(x=>x.account);

foreach(var group in grouped)
{
    foreach(var record in group)
    {
        //your sums
    }
    // your group outputs
}
```

I would use this approach instead of the former.